# Entity Translation and Field Collection

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

[Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) exposes a checkbox on fields, entitled:

> Users may translate all occurrences of this field

When dealing with a [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) field, which of the following should I check the box for?

- Only the field collection field
- Only the child fields
- Both the field collection field, *and* its child fields

Comment: You should only 'Enable translation' for the field collection field (i.e. not its child fields).

Answer (score 1):

Field Collection doesn't support Entity Translation, so my advice is to find another way to achieve your aim.

There is a patch available which has been under development for a long time, use at your own risk.

The Drupal.org issue with it's accompanying patch can be found here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1344672